# Drag and Drop Reorder controls within Grid panel WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, grid-layout

I am almost new to `WPF`.

I have a `Grid panel` shown in the picture. I want to add the drag & drop functionality so that a user can reorder the buttons within the cells of the grid (The user should be able to put the buttons into each cell she wants.)

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="137*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="139*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="112*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="129*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="58*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="59*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="88*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Drag" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
    <Button Content="Drag" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
    <Button Content="Drag" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></Button>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, SO is for asking specific programming questions, not vague "write my entire program for me" requests. If you have a specific problem, (getting a drag image, detecting which grid cell the item is dropped on, etc.) ask that instead.

Comment: Did you find a answer to this question?

Comment: I Want To Do Almost The Same, Did You Found Any Answer To Share With Us?

Comment: See here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html or here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a reorderable GridView control in WPF, you will be disappointed. WPF does not have such a control; it does not even have a GridView. A possible solution would be to upgrade to a XAML based (Universal) app that allows you achieve your goal with ease, as demonstrated by the links in the comments, e.g. the Jerry Nixon [example](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html).

If you are not willing to roll your own and cannot ditch WPF your best bet is buy a UI component that allows you to do just that. There is [Telerik UI](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/overview2) for WPF, [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/grids-and-lists/data-grid), [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/), and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416541/what-is-the-best-ui-component-set-for-wpf)..